# Ionic, firebase __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_firebase_app__.database is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Good evening,
i wrote the error in the title so it makes it easy to know what's the probleme
so i'm new the the ionic and firebase world i'm trying to do a chat app a simple one which consist on a sign in page where the user puts his nickname and after that he will be sent to a room page where he can join any room to start a chat it works fine i was able to make some people chating and creating rooms, and then i decided to make it a bit better by adding a authentication system with a sign up and signin pages using always firebase 
the part of signup and signin works fine and after the user logs in the app sends hi to the page where he can put his nickname the probleme is when he does that and press the button i get this error and it drives me crazy

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_firebase_app**.database is not a function

and here is the code behind this

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AddRoomPage } from '../add-room/add-room';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the RoomPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-room',
  templateUrl: 'room.html',
})
export class RoomPage {


 rooms =[];
 ref = firebase.database().ref('chatrooms/');
 
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang(window.navigator.language);
    //translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
   this.ref.on('value', resp =>{
    this.rooms = [];
    this.rooms = snapshotToArray(resp);
   });
  }

  addRoom(){
   this.navCtrl.push(AddRoomPage);
  }
  joinRoom(key){
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage, {
    key:key,
    nickname:this.navParams.get("nickname")
   });
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RoomPage');
  }

}
export const snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
 let returnArr = [];

 snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>{
  let item = childSnapshot.val();
  item.key = childSnapshot.key;
  returnArr.push(item);
 });
 return returnArr;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ 'Room' | translate }}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addRoom()">
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let room of rooms">
      {{room.roomname}}
      <ion-icon name="chatboxes" item-end (click)="joinRoom(room.key)"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```
ref = firebase.database().ref('chatrooms/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` with `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

Comment: thank you it works, and i feel like the stupidest person on earth

Comment: VS Code does that when adding imports automatically. You may not be using VS Code but it does that to me often.